# How to publish aws codecommit url in npm package?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, components, publish

I have react component in aws codecommit.

I want install this component to another project.

example (npm install https://git-codecommit.ap-XXXXX)

How to publish aws codecommit url in npm package?